# Adjust syntax highlighting for region included with syn-include?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I have a terminal color scheme that makes the default highlighting settings for diffs relatively hard to read. To address this, I’ve added my own custom settings inside of `~/.vim/after/syntax/diff.vim`:

```
hi diffAdded term=NONE ctermfg=Green 
hi diffRemoved term=NONE ctermfg=Red
```

This works great for `git diff`, for example, but the customizations do *not* apply when I use `git commit -v`, so I still get unreadable diffs. I looked in the syntax definition for `gitcommit.vim`, and I noticed that it uses `syn include` to create a nested region:

```
" gitcommit.vim
syn include @gitcommitDiff syntax/diff.vim
syn region gitcommitDiff start=/\%(^diff --\%(git\|cc\|combined\) \)\@=/ end=/^\%(diff --\|$\|#\)\@=/ fold contains=@gitcommitDiff
```

Since it looks like it just uses `diff.vim` under the hood, I figured that copying my custom styles to `~/.vim/after/syntax/gitcommit.vim` would do the trick:

```
" identical to diff.vim
hi diffAdded term=NONE ctermfg=Green
hi diffRemoved term=NONE ctermfg=Red
```

Unfortunately, this doesn’t seem to work—vim still uses the default syntax highlighting.

What’s wrong? How can I customize the syntax highlighting for a region included with `syn include`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `:syntax` defines, well, syntax. It says "if text matches this regular expression, it's a string", and so forth. To do so, it assigns a *highlight group*. It doesn *not* say anything about colours.
- `:highlight` says "highlight this group with these colours".

Whatever `:syntax` does is fairly irrelevant if you just want to change some colours. All we need to know is the correct highlight group that is assigned.

This is also how colour schemes work. Colour schemes are nothing more than a set of `highlight` statements for a bunch of standard groups (`String`, `Identifier`, etc.)

There is no need to put `highlight` statements in `~/.vim/after/syntax/diff.vim`, since syntax files don't define these. This is only required for `:syntax` rules.<sup>1</sup> There is also no relation between the diff syntax being used with `syn include` and nested and your custom `highlight` not working.

Simply adding:

```
highlight diffAdded ctermbg=green
highlight diffRemoved ctermbg=red
```

to your vimrc should work.

Note that `highlight`s *are* reset when setting colour schemes  So I typically do:

```
fun! s:color()
    highlight diffAdded ctermbg=green
    highlight diffRemoved ctermbg=red
endfun
call s:color()
augroup my_colors
    autocmd!
    autocmd Colorscheme * call s:color()
augroup end
```

To make sure the custom `highlight`s are always applied.

Perhaps this is the reason it doesn't work for you?

---

<sup>1</sup>: There is one exceptions to this: when you want to link a highlight group to another highlight group. But this is rare.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me, and I was quite surprised that my original attempt didn’t work. Unfortunately, your suggestion didn’t seem to fix things. Is there some way that I could check what highlight group is being used under the cursor or something along those lines? Even running `hi diffAdded term=NONE ctermfg=Green ` directly while editing a commit message doesn’t seem to do anything.

Comment: @AlexisKing Sure, this should give you the highlight group name: `:echo synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')`... I tried this with `git commit -v` by the way, and it works fine for me ... Not sure why it doesn't for you. You can try following the stepts in [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51)

Comment: Weird! After some more inspection, it seems to actually be working, but for some reason the `Green` color renders differently when I run `git commit -v` and `git diff`. Anyway, that’s a separate problem, so I will continue to investigate it myself. Sorry for the small XY problem, and thanks for your help!